# MVC - Sequence contains no elements

Tags: model-view-controller

Everything was working fine so far but I have started to get this error. Can you please help me what is wrong with the code.

my product model

```
public class Product : EntityBase
{
    public Product()
    {
        this.Photos = new List<Photo>();
        this.OrderDetails = new List<OrderDetail>();
        this.Suppliers = new List<Supplier>();
        this.Comments = new List<Comment>();
        this.Ozelliks = new List<Ozellik>();
    }

    [MaxLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Max 100 karakter."), Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public decimal BuyingPrice { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public decimal SalesPrice { get; set; }
    [Required]

    public decimal DiscountedPrice { get; set; }
    public decimal VATRatio { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(250, ErrorMessage = "Max 3050 karakter."), Required]
    public string DescriptionLong { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(250, ErrorMessage = "Max 250 karakter."), Required]
    public string DescriptionShort { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(250, ErrorMessage = "Max 250 karakter."), Required]
    public string Brand { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Size { get; set; }
    public Gender Gender { get; set; }
    public Color Color { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public decimal? Discount { get; set; }
    public int StockQuantity { get; set; }
    public int LineNumber { get; set; }
    public float CommentAvg { get; set; }
    public bool IsNew { get; set; }

    public virtual Mainproduct Mainproduct { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Campaign> Campaigns{ get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    public virtual List<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Supplier> Suppliers { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Photo> Photos { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Ozellik> Ozelliks { get; set; }
}
```

my specification model

```
 public class Ozellik : EntityBase
{
    [Required]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Max 100 karakter."), Required(ErrorMessage = "Bu alan boş geçilemez")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Max 100 karakter.")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

}
```

my controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        List<Product> Products = db.Products.OrderBy(x => x.LineNumber).Where(x => x.IsActive == true).Where(x => x.StockQuantity > 0).ToList();

        ViewBag.Categories = db.Categories.ToList();
        return View(Products);
    }
```

my view

```
@model IEnumerable<Product>

@foreach (Product item in Model.Where(x => x.Category.Name == "Pasta"))
            {
```

I getting the error in this foreach loop. It was working 10 minutes ago. Only thing I have changed I have added new properties to product model. I have updated newly added properties data for old recordings manually from sql server studio. I have checked with breakpoints and getting 5 products in the controller and sending to the view.

What am I missing here? Thanks for your helps.

Comment: I have added product model and specification model

Answer (score 0):

Usually I see the "Sequence contains no elements" when using "Single()" types of commands.

Two improvements, which should help:

1. If you convert the IQueryable<> to a List<> inside the foreach, you should be able to deal with empty lists more easily (and for debugging).

e.g. Model.Where(x => x.Category.Name == "Pasta").ToList()

2. Check for null category, as you may have a product without a category.

e.g. x => x.Category != null && x.Category.Name == "Pasta"

If it was working previously and you mention you updated the schema, the issue is probably an out of date EF model, or you no longer have data which is throwing an error when returning no rows.

Comment: thanks for your help @Russell I have tried two option you mentioned but didnt work unfortunately.

Comment: Have you updated your EF model to make sure it has the latest schema?

Comment: You could also try removing the category filter from the foreach to determine if it is trying to call internally something like: x.Category.Single().Name